# Field Collection Apps for Windows 8

Tags: mobile, windows

I was wondering if any of you out there have experience with any apps that work on windows 8 tablets free or paid?We have a client that wants us to use their tablets for data collection.  i was wondering if some of you out there have used apps for the windows store that you can recommend.

Comment: ArcPad? http://arcpadteam.blogspot.com/2013/01/arcpad-windows-8-beautiful-marriage.html